# Not able to update a particular row in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to update my table webcart ,which has this particular column named "identifier" where all transaction id lies
Now I want to update the status and reason columns for particular identifier
I have tried this

```
$amount=$request->amount;
$status=$request->status;
$reason=$request->unmappedstatus;
$txnid=$request->txnid;
$device = webcart::findOrFail($txnid);
$device->update([
  'amount' => $amount,'status'=>$status,'reason'=>$reason
]);
```

but its not working for obvious reasons ,can someone tell me how to do it and what argument I have to pass in findorfail??

Comment: Is `txnid` PRIMARY KEY field of device table?

Comment: no its not ,thats why I am facing issueany idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since findOrFail method usages primary key of your table you can do the same thing by using where condition just like below
`txnid` is the field of your device table field

```
$amount=$request->amount;
$status=$request->status;
$reason=$request->unmappedstatus;
$txnid=$request->txnid;
$device = webcart::where('txnid',$txnid);
$device->update([
  'amount' => $amount,'status'=>$status,'reason'=>$reason
]);
```

Comment: It gives an error Call to a member function where() on boolean

Answer (score 0):

Try with [model->save()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) method like this, it works for update and insert both.

```
$device = new webcart();
$device->id = $request->id;
$device->txnid = $request->txnid;
$device->amount = $request->amount;
$device->status = $request->status;
$device->unmappedstatus = $request->unmappedstatus;
$device->save();
```

Comment: Its an insert query ,I want something like